# Functional UI component calling from another file - NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm Trying to use global alert component for my NextJs app.Then i can import that component and use wherever the place i want. Below is my Notification component and place i trying to use.It's showing console logs,but not showing alert.

**notificationBar.js**

```
export const Notification = (status, message) => {
   
        console.log("status -->", status)
        if (status === "success") {
            console.log("success --->", message)
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-success">{message}</div>
            );
        } else if (status === "error") {
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">{message}</div>
            );
        } else {
            return null
        }  
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import  {Notification}  from '../components/notificationBar';

const Home = () => {

 const notify = async ()=>{
         Notification("success", "you have won");
    }

return(
 <div>
  <button onClick={()=>notify()}>Click me</button>
 </div>
 )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: currently, you are returning a component from a click handler

Comment: @Davin Tryon  Yes.i want to show my alert once user click that button

Answer (score 0):

You need to define in a root element an area where to put this messages, could be react portal, here you can find an example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-portals